# My code doesn't work properly in Meteor but works on JS fiddle

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been trying to figure out why Meteor doesn't let me test my button but JSfiddle will.I run the code with the meteor command in terminal, it opens up as if its running properly, I input my text but it does not produce a list item. When I copy the code and paste it on js fiddle it works fine.

I'm new to coding and my experience with meteor is very little so I'm sure I'm missing something and its holding up progress to everything else. http://jsfiddle.net/brendanjackson/bf7m7oao/3/

```
<body>
    <div class=category1>
    <h1>Wellness</h1>
    <input type="text" id = "inputtext">
    <button onClick='buttonClicked()'>Click Me!</button>
    <ul id="myText"></ul>
    </div>
</body>



function buttonClicked() {
    var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
    var inputtext = document.getElementById('inputtext').value  ;
        myText.innerHTML += "<li>"+inputtext+"</li>";

}
```

I'm aware that I don't really use meteor the way it was intended but I'm just not on that level yet and I wanted to get familiar with the API and use it for testing. I just want to get my button to work the way it does on JS fiddle while using Meteor(and understand how). Is there anyone out there who can help me figure this out?

PS:I'm trying to get better at asking questions on this site so any help with that in addition to my problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: there's nothing meteor-related in that code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the desired behavior, and the problem or error you are getting.

Comment: Mind showing use how you included the JS in your HTML? Is the console giving something like: `buttonClicked is not defined`?

Comment: I am not a meteor expert either, but your js needs to be scoped properly. What is your file structure like? Further, are you wrapping your js in [events](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/events/) like `Template.templateName.events({});`

Comment: I have not wrapped anything in templates.

Comment: Also the demo I gave you all in fiddle is the only part of my project that I'm having trouble with and I cant get it working a lone on meteor the same way its written on JSfiddle

Comment: penne12: the desired behavior is simply to have input text appear as a list item after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Brendan,

What you need to do is put your HTML in a template in an .html file, something like this:

```
<body>
  {{brendansTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="brendansTemplate">
    <div class=category1>
      <h1>Wellness</h1>
      <input type="text" id = "inputtext">
      <button id="btnBrendan">Click Me!</button>
      <ul id="myText"></ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

...and then in the corresponding *.js file, create a:

```
Template.brendansTemplate.events({
  'click #btnBrendan': function() {
      var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
      var inputtext = document.getElementById('inputtext').value  ;
      myText.innerHTML += "<li>"+inputtext+"</li>";       }
});
```

I recommend you read some of the Meteor info from [here](https://www.yauh.de/best-learning-resources-for-meteorjs/). Enjoy learning Meteor - I think it's a great framework.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with meteor but you can wrap your function in script tags like so:

```
<script>
function buttonClicked() {
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
var inputtext = document.getElementById('inputtext').value  ;
    myText.innerHTML += "<li>"+inputtext+"</li>";
}
</script>
```

That should allow your javascript to function even if you don't use meteor.

Comment: I'm very new to coding and I know that much, couldn't tell you how much further than that though so this is a good explanation

Comment: Blake, this definitely involves Meteor. This isn't really a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more Meteoric way:

**html**

Wrap your html in a *template*. Meteor will provide the `<html>` and `<body>` sections by itself.

```
<template name="myTemplate>
  <div class=category1>
    <h1>Wellness</h1>
    <input type="text" id="inputtext">
    <button>Click Me!</button>
    <ul id="myText"></ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

**js:**

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click button': function(ev){
    var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
    var inputtext = document.getElementById('inputtext').value;
    myText.innerHTML += "<li>"+inputtext+"</li>";
  }
});
```

To be even more meteoric one could use `Sesssion` variables and helper functions instead of manipulating the DOM directly.